# Jasmine JS Framework - Can not find div#ID from loaded fixtures

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, bdd

I have loaded my fixtures with:

`var fixture = loadFixtures("path/fixture.html");`

And I am trying to find one DIV#ID whether it is exists using this below code:

`expect(fixture.find('DIV#ID')).toBe();`

But, I am getting the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined**

Please help me to find my div#id from my **loaded fixtures using JASMINE JS  Framework**.

Comment: Try `TargetExpect($(fixture).find('DIV#ID')).toBe();`

Comment: Now I am getting error: Expected { selector : 'DIV#ID', context : undefined, length : 0 } to be.

Comment: Can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: expect(fixture).toContain('id="ID"'); - This is working fine. But I hope this is not a proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loading/reading fixtures, you have to set the fixtures then.

```
var fixtures =  readFixtures("header.html");
setFixtures(fixtures);
```

From the set fixtures you can find the DOM element like:

```
expect($('body')).toHaveId("DIV#ID");
```

This works for me.